# change color on matplotlib

Tags: colors, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to change the color of my bar chart.
However, it always plots in black.
Where am I mistaken?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    rects = ax.bar(range(len(l)), l, color = 'r')
    ax.set_title('title')
    ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
    ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
    plt.show()
```

I tried with other parameters ('g', 'c' etc.) but the result is always the same.

Comment: If I run your code, it plots red bars on my machine. Seems to work well. Are your bars thick enough so that you see more than just the edgecolor? I set l to `l = np.random.randn(10)`

Comment: you're completely right, the problem is with the thickness of my bars. Thanks